# How do I power this SAN safely and with redundancy on the power circuits?

Tags: storage-area-network, electrical-power

Location: USA

We are looking at powering a new Storage Area Network (VNXe3200).
There are 10 units in total, each with two power supplies for redundancy.

Assuming we can do either single-phase 120V or 220V AC input, how many circuits and at what amperage do we need for this?
We want to have power redundancy so that one circuit can go down without immediately tripping the other.

I have come up with what I believe is a good solution but my coworker is coming up with something *completely* different, with numbers that I believe are...nuts.

(The power circuits are meant to power only the SAN and nothing else.)

We will have an electrician come in later on, and may contact the vendor for their input, but I wanted to get some early input.

Electrical Specs:

[image]

Comment: Is this in a datacenter? Most datacenters provide A/B power circuits, meaning you can plug each PSU into a different circuit, giving you the redundancy you need.

Comment: You would need about 3kVA based on 2.7kw which gives a little more then the units require.

Comment: Yes this is in a datacenter and we are evaluating whether we need to have facilities run more power circuits.

Comment: I think the question we are really trying to answer is, if we power this with two separate circuits, what amperage must they be? Like "you will need 2x 30A circuits to power at 120V" or "you will need 2x 20A circuits to power at 220V".

Comment: Also thank you @Drifter104, that's almost exactly what I've been coming up with.

Comment: Based on my numbers above and rounded up. 28A at 110v so 14 at 220v